# Problems copy constructing a dynamically allocated object

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, dynamic-allocation

I'm working through an Introduction to C++ and I have a problem involving the use of copy constructors.
The idea of the exercise is to construct a Telephone object, which itself constructs a Housing, a Cable, a Dialer and a Headset. This all works quite well and instructive as each class gives a cout when it gets called, but something goes wrong when I try the following.

The Dialer constructs an array of 12 Buttons. The Buttons-class looks as follows:

```
class Button {
public:

  Button() { std::cout << "Button Constructor " << this << std::endl ; }
  Button(const Button&) { std::cout << "Button Copy Constructor " << this << std::endl ; }
  ~Button() { std::cout << "Button Destructor " << this << std::endl ; }

private:

} ;
```

My first shot at the Dialer class uses static allocation of the Buttons, and that works well. Code:

```
class Dialer {
public:

  Dialer() {        std::cout << "Dialer Constructor " << this << std::endl ; }
  Dialer(const Dialer &dialer) : buttons(dialer.buttons) {      std::cout << "Dialer Copy Constructor " << this << std::endl ; }
  ~Dialer() { std::cout << "Dialer Destructor " << this << std::endl ; }

private:

  Button buttons[12] ;

} ;
```

Next step in the exercise is to allocate the Buttons dynamically, and that's where the fun begins. The following piece of code works:

```
class Dialer {
public:

  Dialer() : buttons(new Button[12]) { std::cout << "Dialer Constructor " << this << std::endl ; }

  Dialer(const Dialer &dialer) {
        buttons = new Button[12];
        std::cout << "Dialer Copy Constructor " << this << std::endl ;
    }

  ~Dialer() {
            delete[] buttons;
            std::cout << "Dialer Destructor " << this << std::endl ;
    }

private:

  Button* buttons ;
} ;
```

But of course this doesn't call the Button copy constructor. I've tried numerous things:

```
buttons = new Button(dialer.buttons)[12];
buttons = new Button(dialer.*buttons)[12];
*buttons = dialer.*buttons;
```

But I just can't work it out. All these attempts give an error that there is no matching function defined in the Button class.

I would appreciate any help :)

Cheers,
GeneralDuke

Answer (score 1):

The following code snippet calls a copy constructor :

```
 Button b;
 Button a=b; // copy constructor called
```

Or for your arrays :

EDIT changed to pass by value.

```
void addToArray(Button* arr, Button aButton, int idx)
{
    arr[idx]=aButton;
}

buttons = new Button[12];

for (int i=0;i<12;i++)
{
     addToButtons(buttons,dialer.buttons[i],i);
}
```

Please note that you have the copy constructor defined on the Button class, not on a  ArrayOfButtons class.

EDIT : dependency injection sample added

I don't rly think you need to use copy constructor on your Dialer + Button relation, more like your Dialer + Phone relation .

Here's a sample where you use copy constructor (but it takes a modified constructor as well) :

```
    class Dialer
    {
       public:
         ...
         Dialer(Button& but):b(but){};
         ....
       private:
         Button b;
    }
```

Snippet :

```
    {
         Button b1;
         Dialer d(b1);
    }
```

For 12 buttons you will end up using 12 arguments at initialization. Maybe you should stick to dynamic allocation rather then pass by value for the array and use the copy constructor for other classes ?

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. If I implement your proposal, it still calls the Button constructor and not the Button copy constructor. I think there isn't a great difference in which one of these gets called, but the exercise states Dialer should call the copy constructor. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: Edited to use pass by value. Usually copy constructors are used when returning or passing by value some objects.

Comment: First, the constructor gets called 12 twelve times (because of buttons = new Button[12];). Next, indeed a copy constructor gets called but it gets destructed immediately afterwards. I don't think this is the solution too...

Furthermore, the exercise doesn't mention that I should introduce some new function whatsoever. It simply states "Modify the constructor, destructor and copy constructor to implement this change"

Answer (score 1):

The following code format calls the copy constructor.

```
Button a;
Button b=a; //calls the copy constructor of Button class
Button c;
c = a; // calls the overload assignment operator, but not the copy constructor.!
```

In your case, for the array of instances,

```
buttons = new Button[12];

for (int i=0;i<12;i++)
{
     buttons[i] = dialer.buttons[i];
}
```

Comment: buttons = new Button[12];

This doesn't call the Copy Constructor does it? Writing

buttons = dialer.buttons;

Doesn't do the job. No second set of Buttons gets constructed and after running I get a "double free or corruption (fasttop)" error.

Comment: @GeneralDuke the second block of code in this post is what he is saying you should put in the copy constructor for Dialer

Answer (score 1):

Using `operator new[]` will construct those `Button`s using their no argument constructor. Further assignments using `=` will call the assignment operator.

If you really need the copy constructor to be called, you have three options:

First, just use `std::vector<Button>` instead of `Button[12]`. This will deal with your allocation and deallocation for you and has the copy semantics which you desire:

```
class Dialer {
public:

    Dialer() : buttons(12) { std::cout << "Dialer Constructor " << this << std::endl ; }

    Dialer(const Dialer &dialer) : buttons(dialer.buttons) {
        std::cout << "Dialer Copy Constructor " << this << std::endl ;
    }

    ~Dialer() { std::cout << "Dialer Destructor " << this << std::endl ; }

private:

    std::vector<Button> buttons;
} ;
```

Your second option is to define the assignment operator in terms of the copy constructor, generally referred to as the *copy-and-swap* idiom:

```
Button& operator= (Button other) { /*do swapping*/ }
```

Your third option is to use `std::allocator` to allocate the memory and construct it in separate steps, allowing you to call the copy constructor to construct the objects (note, never do this in practice; `std::allocator` is generally for implementing generic containers and suchlike, I'm just showing a solution within your constraints):

```
class Dialer {
public:

    Dialer() : buttons() {
        std::allocator<Button> b_alloc;
        buttons = b_alloc.allocate(12);
        for (int i=0; i<12; i++)
        {
            b_alloc.construct(buttons+i); //this line requires C++11
        }

        std::cout << "Dialer Constructor " << this << std::endl ; }

    Dialer(const Dialer &dialer) {
        std::allocator<Button> b_alloc;
        buttons = b_alloc.allocate(12);
        for (int i=0; i<12; i++)
        {
            b_alloc.construct(buttons+i, dialer.buttons[i]);
        }
        std::cout << "Dialer Copy Constructor " << this << std::endl ;
    }

    ~Dialer() {
        std::allocator<Button> b_alloc;
        for (int i=0; i<12; i++)
        {
            b_alloc.destroy(buttons+i);
        }
        b_alloc.deallocate(buttons, 12);
        std::cout << "Dialer Destructor " << this << std::endl ;
    }

private:

    Button* buttons;
} ;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this detailed explanation. The vector-class (is it a class?) is not yet presented, so I don't think I should use that. The same goes for the assignment operator, and as for C++11: I used the older version of C++ for all previous exercises and I think that is required (although it isn't stated anywhere explicitly).

But bottom-line: there is no option without operator assignment, vectors and C++11 that would solve this?

Comment: Not really, what you are trying to do is one of the issues which `std::vector` solves. Are you working through a book or is this for a class? If it's a book, I'd just use `std::vector` and be done with it, if it's for a class, I'd ask for clarification with regards to the assignment operator.